# On scroll change something in the div

Tags: angularjs

I want to change navbar background color when used scrolled down for some px. I am using angular, was trying to set boolean value of navbar to false and when you scroll down it should change to true, if value is true it should change background color of my navbar. Could you give me some help ?

Code:

```js
 public nav__menu: boolean = false;

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    const height = window.pageXOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop || 0;
    if (height > 100) {
      this.nav__menu = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav__menu" [ngStyle]="{background : nav__menu==true ? '#ffffff' : 'none'}"></nav>
```

Comment: This angular 1? Here's Angular example [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6uihdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)